# Javascript Form Shortening - Encoding for UTF-8 conversion

Tags: javascript, loops, encoding

I have a script that we would like to somehow make it smaller instead of repeating it so many times. Is there anyway to make this code shorter so we dont have to create duplicate sets 10 times.

In the textfield we have something like:

```
onKeyUp="replaceWordChars(this.value)
onKeyUp="replaceWordChars2(this.value)
onKeyUp="replaceWordChars3(this.value)

<script>
function replaceWordChars(text) {
var s = text;
s = s.replace(/[\u2018|\u2019|\u201A]/g, "\'");
s = s.replace(/[\u201C|\u201D|\u201E]/g, "\"");
s = s.replace(/\u2026/g, "...");
s = s.replace(/[\u2013|\u2014]/g, "-");
s = s.replace(/\u02C6/g, "^");
s = s.replace(/\u2039/g, "<");
s = s.replace(/\u203A/g, ">");
s = s.replace(/[\u02DC|\u00A0]/g, " ");
document.getElementById("textcounter1").value = s;}

function replaceWordChars2(text) {
var s = text;
s = s.replace(/[\u2018|\u2019|\u201A]/g, "\'");
s = s.replace(/[\u201C|\u201D|\u201E]/g, "\"");
s = s.replace(/\u2026/g, "...");
s = s.replace(/[\u2013|\u2014]/g, "-");
s = s.replace(/\u02C6/g, "^");
s = s.replace(/\u2039/g, "<");
s = s.replace(/\u203A/g, ">");
s = s.replace(/[\u02DC|\u00A0]/g, " ");
document.getElementById("textcounter2").value = s;}

function replaceWordChars3(text) {
var s = text;
s = s.replace(/[\u2018|\u2019|\u201A]/g, "\'");
s = s.replace(/[\u201C|\u201D|\u201E]/g, "\"");
s = s.replace(/\u2026/g, "...");
s = s.replace(/[\u2013|\u2014]/g, "-");
s = s.replace(/\u02C6/g, "^");
s = s.replace(/\u2039/g, "<");
s = s.replace(/\u203A/g, ">");
s = s.replace(/[\u02DC|\u00A0]/g, " ");
document.getElementById("textcounter3").value = s;}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed:

```
function replaceWordChars(text,textcounter) {
var s = text;
s = s.replace(/[\u2018|\u2019|\u201A]/g, "\'");
s = s.replace(/[\u201C|\u201D|\u201E]/g, "\"");
s = s.replace(/\u2026/g, "...");
s = s.replace(/[\u2013|\u2014]/g, "-");
s = s.replace(/\u02C6/g, "^");
s = s.replace(/\u2039/g, "<");
s = s.replace(/\u203A/g, ">");
s = s.replace(/[\u02DC|\u00A0]/g, " ");
document.getElementById(textcounter).value = s;
}
```

call it like:

```
replaceWordChars(text,"textcounter1");
replaceWordChars(text,"textcounter2");
replaceWordChars(text,"textcounter3");
```

from the keyUp event:

```
<... keyUp="replaceWordChars(this.value,this.id)" ...>
```

Comment: That didn't work. I have something like 

<textarea name="txtDesc" id="textcounter1" class="xxl" maxlength="300" onKeyUp="replaceWordChars(text,'textcounter1');">

Comment: Do it like **replaceWordChars(this.value,this.id)**